# How to read an input over 4096 bytes in C++

Tags: c++

I'm now learning how to detect if a given string is a palindrome or not and the problem is that I don't know how to read an input over 4096 bytes in a row. Here is a brief code which would illustrate what I'm gonna do.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

void LCS(char *str, char *reverseStr);

int main(void) {
    int number = 0, index = 0;
    char *str;
    char *reverseStr;
    string buffer;
    char c = 0;

    scanf("%d", &number);
    getchar();

    str = new char[number + 1]();
    reverseStr = new char[number + 1]();

    cin >> buffer;
    strncpy(str, buffer.c_str(), buffer.length() + 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str);i++) {
        reverseStr[i] = str[strlen(str) - 1 - i];
    }


    LCS(str, reverseStr);
    return 0;
}

void LCS(char *str, char *reverseStr) {
    int **matrix;
    int result = strlen(str);

    matrix = new int*[strlen(str) + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str) + 1; i++) {
        matrix[i] = new int[strlen(str) + 1]();
    }


    for (int i = 1; i <= strlen(str); i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= strlen(reverseStr); j++) {
            if (str[i - 1] == reverseStr[j - 1])
                matrix[i][j] = matrix[i - 1][j - 1] + 1;
            else if (matrix[i - 1][j] >= matrix[i][j - 1])
                matrix[i][j] = matrix[i - 1][j];
            else
                matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j - 1];
        }
    }

    result -= matrix[strlen(str)][strlen(reverseStr)];
    cout << result;
}
```

For those who don't wanna read the code above, I want to briefly describe it. I want to read an integer which tells me the size of an string to follow and the reason why I added getchar() function is because I don't want to get any end of line character. After allocating two character array, I want to read an input over 4096 bytes. Below is an example input.

```
4960
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Can you guys tell me why this program won't work?

Comment: Strange mix of using `char*` and `std::string`.

Comment: Find here http://www.w3schools.in/c/program/check-palindrome-string/ i think you help

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  Do you think the reason why there is a problem with input on this program is because I don't strictly choose the kind of data type?

Comment: You're allocating 4096 * 4096 * sizeof(int). You are probably hitting a memory cap, for starters.

Comment: Can you define "won't work"?

Comment: @KishanChauhan Thanks for the info but this isn't the issue I'm looking for

Comment: What issue are you looking for then?

Comment: @cdarke When I copy the test case above, the probram stops reading after getting an input over 4096 bytes. As you can see, the size of the string on the test case is 4960 bytes. I think it's because there is an input buffer overflow or somethign

Comment: What do you mean you don't know how to read over 4096 bytes in a row? And out of curiosity, why are you using matrices to solve this? You could do it with a simple linear iteration from start to middle.

Comment: It is probably because you are reading from the cin object. It probably has a 4k limit (being that it is a c++ object, and you're mixing c and c++ here)

Comment: @ruffles Thanks for the advice but I don't have any options but to use LCS algorithm in order to get the program accepted on a site similar to UVA

Comment: @ruffles Is there any way to solve the memory cap you've mentioned above?

Comment: There is a POSIX standard limit of 4096 on the line length.  Since you are using `cout` then you need `setw` from `<iomanip>`

Comment: I'm just offering up a solution that avoids c++ altogether.... (This is a C forum after all :)  )

Comment: If you are on a POSIX-2008 compliant system, just use `getline()`, and your buffer allocation nightmares are gone.

Comment: Your `strncpy` needs a bounds check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void LCS(char *str, char *reverseStr);

int main(void) {
    char *str = NULL;
    char *reverseStr = NULL;

    // Allocate first string (any size will do)
    size_t number = 10;
    str = malloc( sizeof(char) * (number + 1 ));

    // Make sure it is allocated, or return error code    
    if( !str ) return -2;

    // zero the memory
    memset( &str[0], 0, sizeof(char)*(number+1));


    // Using getline. It will return the actual buffer size to us.
    size_t bufferSize = getline( &str, &number, stdin );

    // How many characters were read?
    printf( "Read in %lu characters (not including null terminator)\n", bufferSize );

    //get rid of the 'enter' at the end. Replace it with a NULL.
    str[bufferSize-1] = 0;

    //Allocate the reversed buffer once we know the size for sure.
    reverseStr = malloc( sizeof(char) * (bufferSize + 1 ));

    //Zero the memory
    memset( &reverseStr[0], 0, sizeof(char)*(bufferSize+1));


    //Copy string in reverse
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
        reverseStr[i] = str[strlen(str) - 1 - i];
    }

    printf( "\nCompare and check that whitespace is gone at both ends:\n" );
    printf( "Original string length: %lu\n", strlen(str));
    printf( "Reversed string length: %lu\n", strlen(reverseStr));

    printf( "Original string:   %s\n", str);
    printf( "Reversed string:   %s\n", reverseStr);

    LCS( str, reverseStr);

    // Cleanup
    free(str);
    free(reverseStr);
    return 0;
}


void LCS(char *str, char *reverseStr) {
    int **matrix;
    int result = strlen(str);

    matrix = (int**)malloc( sizeof(int) * (strlen(str)+1));
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str) + 1; i++) {
        matrix[i] = (int*)malloc( sizeof(int) * (strlen(str)+1));
    }


    for (int i = 1; i <= strlen(str); i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= strlen(reverseStr); j++) {
            if (str[i - 1] == reverseStr[j - 1])
                matrix[i][j] = matrix[i - 1][j - 1] + 1;
            else if (matrix[i - 1][j] >= matrix[i][j - 1])
                matrix[i][j] = matrix[i - 1][j];
            else
                matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j - 1];
        }
    }

    result -= matrix[strlen(str)][strlen(reverseStr)];
    printf( "Result = %d\n", result );

}
```

The output:

```
~/myprograms john  >>./test
radar
Read in 6 characters (not including null terminator)

Compare and check that whitespace is gone at both ends:
Original string length: 5
Reversed string length: 5
Original string:   radar
Reversed string:   radar
Result = -18178288
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. And the thing I want to do is to get the input which is not formatted and consists of 4960 character in a row. According to the advice comments on the question, I need to do something like using setw() function in order to make an input buffer bigger. So why did you use formatBuffer? Does this code read an input and flush at the same time?

Comment: Ok so here's an explanation... 
This is just one possible way to do it. If I knew for example that the string was 100 characters long, I would call
`scanf( "%100s", &str[0] )` to read in 100 characters to `str` (and make sure that the 101'st character was NULL. But since the length is not known til runtime, I make a string called `formatBuffer` with the custom length of `number`. So if the first number you read is 4096, `formatBuffer` will end up as `"%4096s"`. Does that make some sense?

Comment: Understood and gonna give it a try. Thanks

Comment: Hmm... It doesn't solve the problem. Starting from index 4094, the string 'str' consists of null characters till the index reaches 4960.

Comment: as cmaster noted above, you could try using getline(). I'm giving that a shot now...

Comment: I like cmaster's way better.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are hitting some command line limit. I also was not able to pass a string of this size. But I was able to do so using file as an input stream.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

void LCS(const char *sourceStr, char *reverseStr);

int main()
{
    ifstream input_stream;
    const char* filenam = "input_file.txt";

    input_stream.open(filenam);
    if( !input_stream.good() )
    {
        cerr << "couldn't open file: " <<  filenam << "\n";
        return 1;
    }


    string buffer;
    size_t size;
    input_stream >> size;
    input_stream.get();
    std::getline(input_stream, buffer);

    if ( size != buffer.size() )
    {
        cerr << "ambiguous input: size != buffer.size()\n";
        return 1;
    }

    //no need to allocate a new bufer for read only purpose
    const char* raw_str = buffer.c_str();

    //allocate space for reversed string
    char* reverse_str = new char[size];

    LCS(raw_str, reverse_str);

    delete [] reverse_str;

}


void LCS(const char *sourceStr, char *reverseStr){
    //implementation skipped
}
```

There is no need to deep copy of a source string(source Str), because function LCS are not going to modify it.
BTW. There is also an error in function LCS. You cannot use double square brackets here, because the matrix contains multiple chunks of memory("new" was used in a loop).

Comment: This concept of approaching the problem works in linux terminal, though I have no options but to get an input from command line. By redirecting input using <, the program shows a correct result